# Find average grade of 10 students, and increment students

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to ask the final grade of 10 students (**while**) incrementing their values:

So something like:

> Please enter final grade for student 1
>
> Please enter final grade for student 2

and so on... till 10

Then I need to get the grades they entered, and find average.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():

   x = []

   for i in range(10):
      final_grades = x.append(int(input('Please enter final grade for student: ')))


      ##average_final_grade = final_grades / 10

      ##print(average_final_grade)


main()
```

Comment: Append doesn't return anything...

Comment: How do I make it loop through 10 times without append and return something?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# list of grades
x = []
# count of students 
n = 10
# fill list with grades from console input
# using pythonic generator
x = [int(input('Please enter final grade for student {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(n)]
# count average, 
# sum is builtin way to sum values in list
# float required for python 2.x to make avg float, not int
average_final_grade = sum(x) / float(n)
print('Avg grade is {}'.format(average_final_grade))
```

[Online demo](http://code.runnable.com/V75O7syW5IsNknuE/find-average-grade-of-10-students-and-increment-students-for-python).

Comment: Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the values, as you have already done:

```
x = []
for i in range(10):
    x.append(int(input('Please enter final grade for student: ')))
```

Now you need to sum the values of `x`:

```
total_sum = sum(x)
```

Then, you get the average:

```
average_final_grade = total_sum/len(sum)
```

Comment: works to, but solution in bottom also increments students, which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    total=sum(x)
    average=total/10
print(average)
```

## tack this at the bottom and it should work